# Proof of decidability of type checking of calculus of (co)inductive constructions?

Tags: type-theory, decidability, calculus-of-constructions

I often see it asserted that type checking is decidable for CIC, but I haven't seen it proven. Is there a good paper (or simple demonstration) of this?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of this question: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/41192/algorithmic-type-checking-for-calculus-of-inductive-constructions though the latter doesn't explicitly mention a proof of decidability (the references give proofs though)

Comment: There are a number of references linked there, do you know which in particular has the proof?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no proof for CIC itself. But Randy Pollack's paper proves the decidability for PTSes. The proof carries over to the more complex systems essentially unchanged.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found another reference that goes through a detailed proof of the decidability of typechecking for systems of dependent types up to the CIC:

Chapter 2 of [Advanced Topics in Types and Programming Languages](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/attapl/): *Dependent Types*, David Aspinall & Martin Hofmann.

As you probably know, the proof of decidability is conditional on decidability of $\beta$-equality, which itself is implied by the normalization of the calculus.

The proof of that statement is significantly more difficult, partly because it implies consistency of the logical system.